# How to plot multiple lines in R when the x-axes do not align perfectly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot the weight change of my child over time relative to the percentiles provided by the CDC.

I have arranged the CDC weight data into the data frame "cdc_weight_tall", which has three columns:

1. "age": 0, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, etc.
2. "percentile": 10th Percentile, 25th Percentile, 50th Percentile, 75th Percentile, 90th Percentile
3. "weight": 2.7, 3.1, 3.8, etc.

I have plotted the CDC weight data as follows:

```
plot_weight <- ggplot(
  data = cdc_weight_tall,
  aes(x = age, y = weight)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = percentile)) +
  expand_limits(y = 0, x = 0) +
  ggtitle("Weight Plot") +
  labs(y= "Weight (Kg)", x = "Age (Months)")
```

**Question: How do I add my child's weight to this ggplot2 plot?**

Currently, I have arranged my child's weight data into the data frame "baby_weight", which has two columns:

1. "age": 0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, etc.
2. "weight": 3.0, 2.8, 3.2, 3.5, etc.

Here's more detail:

```
> dput(cdc_weight_tall)
structure(list(age = c(0, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 
7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11.5, 0, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 
7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11.5, 0, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 
7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11.5, 0, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 
7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11.5, 0, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 
7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11.5), percentile = c("10th Percentile", 
"10th Percentile", "10th Percentile", "10th Percentile", "10th Percentile", 
"10th Percentile", "10th Percentile", "10th Percentile", "10th Percentile", 
"10th Percentile", "10th Percentile", "10th Percentile", "10th Percentile", 
"25th Percentile", "25th Percentile", "25th Percentile", "25th Percentile", 
"25th Percentile", "25th Percentile", "25th Percentile", "25th Percentile", 
"25th Percentile", "25th Percentile", "25th Percentile", "25th Percentile", 
"25th Percentile", "50th Percentile", "50th Percentile", "50th Percentile", 
"50th Percentile", "50th Percentile", "50th Percentile", "50th Percentile", 
"50th Percentile", "50th Percentile", "50th Percentile", "50th Percentile", 
"50th Percentile", "50th Percentile", "75th Percentile", "75th Percentile", 
"75th Percentile", "75th Percentile", "75th Percentile", "75th Percentile", 
"75th Percentile", "75th Percentile", "75th Percentile", "75th Percentile", 
"75th Percentile", "75th Percentile", "75th Percentile", "90th Percentile", 
"90th Percentile", "90th Percentile", "90th Percentile", "90th Percentile", 
"90th Percentile", "90th Percentile", "90th Percentile", "90th Percentile", 
"90th Percentile", "90th Percentile", "90th Percentile", "90th Percentile"
), weight = c(2.747222257, 3.101767067, 3.770157472, 4.387041982, 
4.95592631, 5.480295205, 5.963510428, 6.408775097, 6.819122283, 
7.197413532, 7.546341788, 7.868436369, 8.166068895, 3.06486465, 
3.437628263, 4.13899376, 4.784820426, 5.379141034, 5.92588831, 
6.428828208, 6.891533095, 7.317373091, 7.709516114, 8.070932165, 
8.404399764, 8.712513432, 3.39918645, 3.79752846, 4.544776513, 
5.230584214, 5.859960798, 6.437587751, 6.967850457, 7.454854109, 
7.902436186, 8.314178377, 8.693418423, 9.043261854, 9.366593571, 
3.717519384, 4.145593668, 4.946765504, 5.680083196, 6.351511983, 
6.966523789, 7.53018045, 8.047178246, 8.52187726, 8.958324062, 
9.360270982, 9.7311934, 10.07430572, 3.992572231, 4.450125603, 
5.305632496, 6.08764077, 6.802769825, 7.45711879, 8.056331004, 
8.605635546, 9.109878097, 9.573546299, 10.00079194, 10.3954511, 
10.76106284)), row.names = c(NA, -65L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
> dput(baby_weight)
structure(list(age = c(7.93333333333333, 6.2, 5.03333333333333, 
4.1, 3.5279398148147, 3.06166666666662, 2.71905092592594, 2.69418981481479, 
2.26203703703698, 1.51789351851864, 1.11550925925937, 1.09291666666662, 
0.729652777777665, 0.497268518518589, 0.294189814814793, 0.11949074074073, 
0.00555555555547471), weight = c(7.7, 6.7, 6.6, 6.1, 5.7, 5.7, 
5.5, 5.6, 4.8, 4.6, 4.2, 4, 3.8, 3.5, 3.2, 2.8, 3)), row.names = c(NA, 
-17L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Subquestions:

- How do I label the percentile lines?
- How do I change the color of each of the six lines?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: To add a line for your baby weights try `+ geom_line(data = baby_weight)`. For the labelling. Simple solution. Map percentile e.g. on color, i.e.  `geom_line(aes(color= percentile, group = percentile))`. Adds a color legend with the labels.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(cdc_weight_tall)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(cdc_weight_tall, 20))`. And the same for `baby_weight`.

Comment: Thanks @stefan! That tip does basically get me pretty close to where I wanted to be.
@RuiBarradas; I've added sample data.